# Hide edit & delete button for last row in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gridview, datarow

I have a gridview and few columns in gridview have amount calculations. And I have added a new datarow at the last of the gridview which sums up the column values and displays.

But the last row in gridview has edit and delete button visible and how could I possibly hide those two images from last row?

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvDetails" DataKeyNames="UserId,UserName" runat="server"
        AutoGenerateColumns="false" CssClass="Gridview" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#61A6F8"
        ShowFooter="true" HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="true" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White"
        onrowcancelingedit="gvDetails_RowCancelingEdit"
        onrowdeleting="gvDetails_RowDeleting" onrowediting="gvDetails_RowEditing"
        onrowupdating="gvDetails_RowUpdating">
    <Columns>

        <asp:TemplateField>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:ImageButton ID="imgbtnUpdate" CommandName="Update" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/update.jpg" ToolTip="Update" Height="20px" Width="20px" />
                <asp:ImageButton ID="imgbtnCancel" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" ImageUrl="~/Images/Cancel.jpg" ToolTip="Cancel" Height="20px" Width="20px" />
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:ImageButton ID="imgbtnEdit" CommandName="Edit" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/Edit.jpg" ToolTip="Edit" Height="20px" Width="20px" />
                <asp:ImageButton ID="imgbtnDelete" CommandName="Delete" Text="Edit" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/delete.jpg" ToolTip="Delete" Height="20px" Width="20px" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ID">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblID" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("ID") %>'/>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblID" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("ID") %>'/>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Profit">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtProfit" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Profit") %>'/>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblProfit" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Profit") %>'/>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Amount">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtAmount" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Amount") %>'/>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblAmount" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Amount") %>'/>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

    </Columns> 
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Can you post the markup of the grid view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can hide them programatically:

```
var lastRow = gvDetails.Rows[gvDetails.Rows.Count - 1];
lastRow.FindControl("imgbtnEdit").Visible = false;
lastRow.FindControl("imgbtnDelete").Visible = false;
```

Ideally this should be done after grid view is data bound and has all rows (including the last one), but as a last resort you can use `Page_PreRender`.

Comment: When I use page indexing for each page the row doesn't have edit and delete button. How can I fix that?

Comment: @Vicky, that depends on where your last summation row appears. Is it on the last page, or on every page?

Comment: It happens for each page.

Comment: @Vicky, right, I understand. The problem is you still probably want to hide these buttons for the final summation row. Currently we do this for the last row of those grid is currently displaying, which is not always the summation row. So to solve the problem correctly we need to understand how to distinguish last row on every page and the summation row

Comment: Yes correct. The summation row will be the very last row in gridview.

Answer (score 1):

The Best place for summation data is in the footer, that will take care of having the command controls as they are not added to the footer.

See: [Displaying Summary Data in the Footer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972833.aspx)

Also: [What is the XY Problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Example (should be easy to convert to C#):

```
'Note Global Declaration
Dim Total1 As Double = 0
Dim Total2 As Double = 0

Protected Sub GridView1_RowDataBound _
    (sender As Object, e As GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowDataBound    

    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then

        Dim drv as DataRowView = CType(e.Row.DataItem, DataRowView)

        ' Perform summations on Data rows
        Total1 += CDbl(drv("<column_name>").ToString())
        Total2 += CDbl(drv("<other_column_name>").ToString())

    ElseIf e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.Footer Then

        ' Place results in footer cells
        e.Row.Cells(2).Text = "Total: " & Total1.ToString()
        e.Row.Cells(3).Text = "Total: " & Total2.ToString()
    Endif
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

set visibility of your edit & delete button column to false. You can set the column index accordingly.

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
{
        e.Row.Cells[0].Visible = false;   //0 is autogenerate edit column index
        e.Row.Cells[1].Visible = false;  // 1  is autogenerate delete column index
}
}
```